# How to get return result in else if?

Tags: php

```
...} else if (isset(RegexValidation::isMMYY($column)[0])) {
     $row[] = $this->setValue("mmyy", $column, $indexrow, $columnindex);
   } else if ($res = RegexValidation::isMMYYShort($column)) {
     $row[] = $this->setValue("mm", $res[1], $indexrow, $columnindex);
     $row[] = $this->setValue("yy", $res[2], $indexrow, $columnindex);
}
```

Is it possible to get return result `$res` in else if statement

`else if ($res = RegexValidation::isMMYYShort($column)) {}`

Comment: That is what you implemented. So what is your _real_ question?

Comment: What do you mean by "return result"? There's no occurence of `$res`  in the first snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, Try like below,

```
else if ($res == RegexValidation::isMMYYShort($column)) 
{ 
   return $res; 
}
```